# Python function not returning None instead of list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a function that is to return a list of tuples. I have tried printing the list in the `for` loop before the `return` statement, and it works fine. However, when I call the function, it returns `None`

```
def list_path(first, last):   
    path = []
    # ..... shortened code   
    while True:
        for x, y in neighbors(person.id):            
            # ... some more code                
            nextPair = (x, y)                                
            path.append(nextPair)                   
    return path
```

This is how i call the function
`path = list_path(source, target)`

I have an if statement that uses the value of path after the function call. The value is always `None`, even when I hardcode the list

Comment: You need to provide more code to get meaningful answers. The bit you shared looks right. Are you *sure* this is the only return statement in the function?

Comment: This information is not sufficient, you have to add more code

Comment: What is "some more code"? As shown, this function *never* returns, because there's no way to end the `while` loop. Is there a bare `return` statement in there somewhere?

Comment: My guess is that you use `return` instead of `break` at some point in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. At some point in my code, I returned without any value. This return statement is different from the one located at the last line of the function.
Thanks for your comments.